# How can I list installed packages on a Debian based system that are NOT part of the base distribution

Tags: apt, package-management, raspbian

I have a Raspbian system which I need to list all the packages that have been installed since the machine was setup.

Obviously I can show what now is installed, but I'd like just a list of the packages that did not come with the distribution... ie the ones that have been installed since the machine had been setup.

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: thanks for the dupe warning... it seems 30 mins of googlefoo failed me this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the history of what you have installed by viewing the `apt-get` history file here: `/var/log/apt/history.log`

[Source](https://serverfault.com/questions/175504/how-do-i-get-the-history-of-apt-get-install-on-ubuntu)